# C- Is it right to read binary txt file?

Tags: c, malloc, header-files, binaryfiles

I am beginner of C language.

I am trying to read a binary txt file.

When I just opened the txt file directly, I saw it

> - 젂 8 F ? ㎲?잤Oタsp쑴톧숴沛=)麴퓠5?r!오?쏠AD풠-V욕?C珞?|붆拂쟬v????걀신v?@n풶1c퓋?>p璉>5쾳엥V壤?뾅A癬A?Αw
>     殆퀃[??픫퇡원?퓅V맙°쐴??閣?W條>걬벩3쁂횖?l?젖?옜鸚?d乍?涌h??伽?Y뤍XK?묠?RT?테?@숦 ?vY햙y?kz'?n?6註웍Qt??*풯?인$???쾹y옇왯?L쁂碻?祠녋Dm+작\藪왱여?픻9c욋??출풛 궭母?좣?孔8퓎뒜C=瑾A??+샓?쇏\꾟퐾岫?j?s蕣풖M픑?앝I폹?=?f쏜 쌒뎠??빦갈i?_$?掠?;????2&풰Е?U윰i녉U?푂?풧+쁂-暉A倫겵헳퐉lg퓾닆욋ⓨ풇짡?믳빢쨒榕:@?뺠?쏱요p殆쩋쁂M됆A??욢??돽p瑥푢

Yes, the things in the txt file seem to be weird because it presents binary things.

The file consists of header and data.

The Header are

> nSamples        - number of samples in file (4-byte integer)
>
> sampPeriod      - sample period in 100ns units (4-byte integer)
>
> sampSize        - number of bytes per sample (2-byte integer)
>
> parmKind        - a code indicating the sample kind (2-byte integer)

and 4byte float type of data part.

My code is really doing well about the Header part.

but I don't know why it is going worse in the data part.

The data part seems to be wrong in my code because they have same values except data[0]

Actually, they all have different values.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h> // exit()



  int main(void) 
  {

    FILE *a;



    int abc=1;
    int ch;
    int size;
    int k;

    float* data;
    long* nSamples;
    long* sampPeriod;
    short* sampSize;
    short* sampKind;

    nSamples=(long*) malloc(sizeof(long));
    sampPeriod=(long*) malloc(sizeof(long));
    sampSize=(short*) malloc(sizeof(short));
    sampKind=(short*) malloc(sizeof(short));
    data=(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*10);
    //I Just wanted to check a few values 

    if ( (a = fopen("noalter.txt", "rb")) == NULL ) {
      fputs("error!", stderr);
      exit(1);
    }

    fread(nSamples,sizeof(long),1,a);
    fread(sampPeriod,sizeof(long),1,a); 
    fread(sampSize,sizeof(short),1,a); 
    fread(sampKind,sizeof(short),1,a);

    fread(data,sizeof(float),1,a);
    fread(data,sizeof(float),1,a);
    fread(data,sizeof(float),1,a);

    printf("%ld \n",nSamples[0]);
    printf("%ld \n",sampPeriod[0]);
    printf("%d \n", sampSize[0]);
    printf("%d \n", sampKind[0]);
    printf("%f \n", data[0]);
    printf("%f \n", data[1]);
    printf("%f \n", data[2]); //I Just wanted to check a few values 


    fclose(a); 
    free(nSamples);
    free(sampPeriod);
    free(sampSize);
    free(sampKind);

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: For a start get rid of your mallocs and frees and just pass the address of the vars to fread. You don't need the added problems for your example. You can always convert to dynamic memory allocation when you know your stuff is working.

Comment: ya. In which format you are writing you need to read in the same format!

Comment: What is a "binary txt file"?

Comment: @ScottHunter a file witch a .schrö extension.

Comment: @Thank you for all. "binary txt file" means that the contents represent binary things so it is impossible to see it directly in txt file. Because I am so awkward to deal with C language and I will take you guys's comment for solving the problem

Comment: So it's just a "binary file" then!? The main thing that is "wrong" here is that you chose to give the file a .txt extension.  That is misleading and typically the extension will be associated with a text editor/viewer.  In your case whatever you viewed the file with appears to have assumed it is Unicode.

Comment: BTW: Good idea to check result of `fread()`.

Comment: @Clifford Is there any format that I can transform without problem instead of txt file?  Thank you for comment !

Comment: @chux Thank you for your comment! I will do it

Comment: @user2874612 : You do not understand my point. The file is not a text file.  The extension is just part of the name, it is a convention to use .txt to indicate plain text, here it is inappropriate, but does not affect the code or the interpretation of the file at all.  The file is binary and you are reading it is binary - all good - the file is just unconventionally named as it is not a txt file.  Just call it .dat to .bin or even .myproprietarybinaryformatfile - it does not matter except you should not flout well understood conventions.

Comment: @Clifford Thank you for kind reply. Oh your explanation is so nice and the file is binary and I tried to read binary. It is okay to read in C. In addtion, If I want to express the binary things that I will call it .dat and .bin ! So thankful to your reply again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading the data, you read into the same position of `data` all three times. You should do e.g.

```
fread(&data[0], sizeof(data[0]), 1, a);
fread(&data[1], sizeof(data[1]), 1, a);
fread(&data[2], sizeof(data[2]), 1, a);
```

Or just read all ten entries you have allocated:

```
fread(data, sizeof(data[0]), 10, a);
```

Comment: unbelievable!! Thank you so much. So gorgeous!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux the contents of the binary file can also be used using *cat* command.

Comment: Thank you for advice. When I try to this in Linux, I remember it!